# Looping through quiz questions fails

Tags: c#, winforms

*Edited* - I posted an earlier version of my code originally, correct code now below

I have a database table of quiz questions that I am displaying in my form, however, when I get to the last question in the table I get the following error:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
There is no row at position 5
```

My table structure is like this:

Question Number | Question | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3 | Answer 4 | Correct Answer

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class QuizQuestions : Form
{
    public WindowsAnalysisQuiz()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //int questionNumber;
    String correctAnswer;
    private void WindowsAnalysisQuiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declare connection string using windows security
        string cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hanna\\Desktop\\QuizQuestions.accdb";

        //declare Connection, command and other related objects
        OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

        //try
        //{
        //open connection
        conGet.Open();
        //String correctAnswer;

        cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

        cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions ORDER BY rnd()"; 

        OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();
        label1.Text = reader["Question"].ToString();
        radioButton1.Text = reader["Answer 1"].ToString(); 
        radioButton2.Text = reader["Answer 2"].ToString();
        radioButton3.Text = reader["Answer 3"].ToString();
        radioButton4.Text = reader["Answer 4"].ToString();
        correctAnswer = reader["Correct Answer"].ToString();
        //questionNumber = 0;

        conGet.Close();

    }

    private void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\QuizQuestions.accdb";
        int questionNumber = 0;
        //declare Connection, command and other related objects
        OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

        //try
        {
            //open connection
            conGet.Open();

            cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

            cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions ORDER BY rnd()"; // select all columns in all rows

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            String chosenAnswer = "";
            //int chosenCorrectly = 0;
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 1"].ToString();
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 2"].ToString();
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 3"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 4"].ToString();
            }

            if (chosenAnswer == reader["Correct Answer"].ToString())
            {
                labelQuestion.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Question"].ToString();
                //and show possible answers:
                radioButton1.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 1"].ToString();
                radioButton2.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 2"].ToString();
                radioButton3.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 3"].ToString();
                radioButton4.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 4"].ToString();
                correctAnswer = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Correct Answer"].ToString();
                questionNumber++; //got to next question! 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("That is not the correct answer");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

What I am trying to do is to get a for loop that will list the questions in my database but in a way that allows me to add up all of the answers answered correctly when the final question has been answered, and of course, not getting the error that I am getting

Comment: Lot of bad coding practices in this code dup strings, instance variables that should be local, messy implied disposal on OldDbX...X objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your starting value for `questionNumber` needs to be 0 since Rows is zero based, otherwise `table.Rows[questionNumber]` will fail for the last row.

Comment: Also there is no limit to what questionNumber will be, so every time the button is pressed you increment questionNumber. Unless you have not shown all the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the questionNumber initial value to 0 since the rows zero based.And get the count of the questions in pageload and set it another variable as int questionCount that
you can reach it in buttonClick.

in buttonClick change the questionNumber++ with questionNumber= (questionNumber++%questionCount);

it will turn to the begining whne the questions finished.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in btnGoToNextOne_Click unconditionally increments questionNumber (questionNumber++) every time a correct answer is chosen.  When the last question is correctly chosen, the questionNumber index is out of range, so that COULD be a problem somewhere else in your code.

The other thig is that in Form1_Load, you set questionNumber = 1 which assumes that you have at least 2 questions in your db.  Unless you set questionNumber to 1 for some reason, it should probably be set to 0 (as indexes in C# are zero-based).

There is also a LOT to be desired the way you are doing things in this code, duplicate strings, OleDbX...X objects that should be wrapped in using(OleDbX...X) {} so that they are disposed properly; why DataTable table is not a local variable, I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

You should tell the compiler to end if that is the last row i.e you should add this..

```
if (chosenAnswer == reader["Correct Answer"].ToString() && 
    questionNumber <= tables[your table].rows.count())
```